# How to prevent Netty from removing handlers when channel is closed?

Tags: netty

I am using Netty 4.1.65.Final.  We have a proxy service that receives requests from a client and we forward that request to the downstream server. We therefore have two channels/pipelines, one with the upstream client and one with the downstream server.

Upstream Client <-- Upstream Channel --> Proxy <-- Downstream Channel --> Downstream server

There is a case where the upstream client disconnects while we are still processing the downstream response on the downstream channel. Netty closes the upstream channel and as part of its cleanup process removes all the handlers in the pipeline. When we go to write the downstream response to upstream channel (and back to the upstream client), the outbound handlers are not executed since they were removed. These handlers contain core logic that needs to be executed.

Is the only solution to re-add the outbound handlers before writing to the upstream channel and cleaning up the handlers afterwards in a listener?

It may be possible to move the core logic to a listener, but it's not ideal since we need access to the HttpResponse object. The outbound handlers are ideal for this.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no way to do this. The removal of the handlers is needed to ensure cleanup is done and so `handlerRemoved(...)` is called.

Comment: Thanks for answering Norman, not just this question but others. They have helped a lot!

I went ahead and did the workaround, which is to re-add the outbound handlers to the closed channel, write the response (which will fail), but the core logic in the outbound handlers are now executed. The listener attached to the write future then removes the outbound handlers from the channel again.